# Do post method for http response

Tags: android

Using `Httpclient`, how to parse json data.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
apiResponse.code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

if (apiResponse.code == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
{
    httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    apiResponse.response = new String(EntityUtils.toString(httpentity));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step in retrieving any API-based model data is to execute a network request to retrieve the JSON response that represents the underlying data that we want to use

{

"businesses": [

{

```
  "id": "yelp-tropisueno",
  "name" : "Tropisueno",
  "display_phone": "+1-415-908-3801",
  "image_url": "http://anyurl/ms.jpg",

}
```

] 
}

Let's create a Java class that will act as the Business model in our application:

```
public class Business {
private String id;
private String name;
private String phone;
private String imageUrl;

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return this.phone;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return this.imageUrl;
}}
```

we need to add method that would manage the deserialization of a JSON dictionary into a populated Business object:

```
public class Business {  public static Business fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
Business b = new Business();

try {
    b.id = jsonObject.getString("id");
        b.name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        b.phone = jsonObject.getString("display_phone");
        b.imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("image_url");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

return b;  }}
```

and successfully create a Business with Business.fromJson(json). However, in the API response, we actually get a collection of business JSON in an array. So ideally we also would have an easy way of processing an array of businesses into an ArrayList of Business objects. That might look like:

```
public class Business {  public static ArrayList<Business> fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray) {
  ArrayList<Business> businesses = new ArrayList<Business>(jsonArray.length());

  for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject businessJson = null;
      try {
        businessJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          continue;
      }

      Business business = Business.fromJson(businessJson);
      if (business != null) {
        businesses.add(business);
      }
  }

  return businesses;  }}
```

With that in place, we can now pass an JSONArray of business json data and process that easily into a nice ArrayList object for easy use in our application with Business.fromJson(myJsonArray).

JSONArray businessesJson = apiResponse.response.getJSONArray("businesses");

ArrayList businesses = Business.fromJson(businessesJson);

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is deprecated use HttpUrlConnection instead :

```
try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      InputStream is = null;
      OutputStream os = null;
      try {

        conn.setReadTimeout(_readTimeout);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(_connectTimeout);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Date", _date );

        if(mbIsGET){// Get Request
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }else{ // Post Request
          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setDoOutput(true);

          os = conn.getOutputStream();
          BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                  new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
          writer.write(_PostRequest);
          writer.flush();
          writer.close();
          os.close();
        }

        conn.connect();

        int code = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
          //do something with response
          is = conn.getInputStream();
          BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
          StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

          String inputStr;
          while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
            responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

          inputStr = responseStrBuilder.toString();

          if(mbIsGET){Result = parseResponseGET(inputStr);}
          else{Result = parseResponsePOST(inputStr);}
        }


      } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        //clean up
        try {
          if (is != null) is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();
      }
```

You can cast the response into a JsonObject with : `new JSONObject(inputStr)`

Answer (score -1):

Use this below mehtod for json parsing

public static ApiResponse **doPost**(String url, ArrayList params) throws Exception {
        ApiResponse apiResponse = null;

```
    HttpEntity httpentity = null;

    Log.print("WebInterface :: dopost() :; URL", url);
    Log.debug("WebInterface :: dopost() :; URL", url);

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
        apiResponse.code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (apiResponse.code == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            apiResponse.response = new String(EntityUtils.toString(httpentity));
        }

        Log.print("WebInterface :: dopost() :: ", " Code ::: " + apiResponse.code + " <BR/> Response :: " + apiResponse.response);
        Log.debug("WebInterface :: dopost() :: ", " Code ::: " + apiResponse.code + " <BR/> Response :: " + apiResponse.response);

        // release
        httpentity = null;
        httpResponse = null;
        httppost = null;
        httpclient = null;
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return apiResponse;
}
```